# Efficient way to find $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2})]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I want to show rigorously that this is 2. I'm sure there's a faster way than by trying to see if $\sqrt{5} = a + b \sqrt{2} + c \sqrt{3} + d \sqrt{6}$ (linear combination of the basis elements for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2})$). I'm just not sure what.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713529/finding-basis-of-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt5-over-mathbbq?rq=1

Comment: You can go with the top answer's route via solving equations or with Jyrki's answer where he uses the Galois correspondence. Without using the Galois correspondence, I think this is just a messy slog through a system of equations.

Comment: Do you know Kummer theory?

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the polynomial $x^2-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ by considering $x^2-5\bmod 23$ and noting that $23$ splits completely in $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$.

Edit:  Let $K=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ and $O_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$.  If we knew $x^2-5$ was irreducible over $K$ we'd know $K[\sqrt{5}:K]=2$.  What we'd like to find is a prime $p$ for which $x^2-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$ and $p$ splits completely in $O_K$.  Then for a $\frak{p}$ in $O_K$ lying over $p$ we'll have $x^2-5$ is irreducible over $O_{K}/\frak{p}$, hence irreducible over $K$.  By trial and error using the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{5}{23}\right)=-1, \left(\frac{2}{23}\right)=1,\text{ and} \left(\frac{3}{23}\right)=1$, so $23$ is a prime which satisfies all the requirements.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it explained in a little more detail.

Comment: @AlfredYerger  Just trying to keep it "fast."  Probably too fast though.

Answer (score 1):

See Bill Dubuque's proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30687/) and Iurie Boreico's proof [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf). See also [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36129/),
 [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150141/), [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/), [[4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1496567/), [[5]](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/).